# count execution of specific commands

Tags: linux, build-process, build-automation

How can I count how often a specific program / command is launched under linux?

Can I avoid a wrapper-shell-script ?

I need to count and measure my build cycle to convince management of better tools :-)

Answer (score 0):

systemtap's [fork tracer](http://vickypark.com/doc/systemtap-1.4/examples/process/forktracker.stp) could be he answer.Just adjust it to your needs.

Comment: looks interesting, but I am not allowed to install systemtap.

Answer (score 0):

This commend line will prompt the most frequently used commands you type :

```
history | awk '{print $2}' | awk 'BEGIN {FS="|"}{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail | sort -nr
```

That produce (in my case) :

```
 104 reset
 89 ll
 78 cd
 52 sudo
 45 ssh
 45 ./unittest.sh
 44 ps
 38 python
 37 man
 29 ls
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if an alias counts as a shell wrapper script ... if not, then something like the following will count the number of times the aliased command (ls in this case) is run.  Create a file named `~/counter` with a zero in it up front and this will increment it each time.

```
alias ls='awk "{print \$1+1}" ~/counter > ~/counter.new ; mv ~/counter.new ~/counter ; ls'
```